# How to render html tags from mysql database in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am storing html tags like `<ul><li>....</li></ul>`, etc in the table. I want to retrieve these values as html content. When I retrieve this data I want to show it as HTML content, that is, it should show bullets instead of `<ul><li>....</li></ul>`.

Code which I am trying:

```
<?php echo stripslashes($row3['description'])?>
```

I have even tried `htmlentities()`, `html_entity_decode()` but, none have worked.

Comment: Yeah, it shows output as `<ul> <li>......</li></ul>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can Use **`htmlspecialchars_decode`** function as below :

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row3['description']));
```

Instead of

```
 echo stripslashes($row3['description']);
```

You can know more about function here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Answer (score 14):

**for laravel users just do this**

```
{!! $my_db_ish['my_row'] !!}
```

**instead of**

```
{{ $my_db_ish['my_row'] }}
```

Comment: Any other options? And why?

Comment: dunno if there are other options for now, but i know the first will not escape values from the database while the second will auto escape the values from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Use [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode).

```
$str = "<ul><li></li></ul>";

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to display the html content is to simply `echo $row3['description']`, however, this leaves you open to vulnerabilities and unless you really trust the data (ie: never) then you should clean it up first. You can try [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Dont call any

> stripslashes, htmlentities or html_entity_decode

These are function to prevent HTML code to be processed as HTML Code (It turns it into text). Just Try to `echo $row3['description'];`.
And make sure to end your lines with `;`!!

You should also check if you are saving the data the correct way into the MySQL databae (So it's no changed to prevent HTML coding in the database).

Also it isn't very safe to use HTML code that is saved in a MySQL database that a USER is also involved in. He might add his own HTML code with out you wanting him too, so WATCH OUT!!

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlspecialchars_decode() function. Its works fine for me...

Use guideline

Your Text with code

```
<?php

    $text = " 
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.
    </body>
    </html> ";

    OR

    $text = $row['columnname'];  // Here define your database table column name.

    echo htmlspecialchars_decode($text);  

?>
```

Output:

Reference site about Lorem Ipsum, giving information on its origins, as well as a random Lipsum generator.